# Symfony2 cronjob environment not found

Tags: php, symfony, cron

I am trying to run a Symfony2 command with a cron job  but I get an error that the environment is not found. Here is my cron job:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /usr/lib/myApp/app/console >> /usr/lib/myApp/forumLog.txt 2>&1
```

For now I am just trying to make app/console work and the expected output is a list with all commands. The error that I get is:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
User Error: The environment was not found
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong and what is the correct way to run symfony2 commands through cronjob?

Answer (score 1):

In my own Symfony-console running cronjobs, I usually have cron run a shell script, that first changes into the apprppriate directory, and then runs the console command.

Here's an example that has been running for a year or two:

File: `/etc/cron.d/systemChecks` (run a shell script as user: www-user)

```
10 7,19 *  * * www-data /var/www/dir.../bin/liipMonitor.sh
```

File: `/var/www/dir.../bin/liipMonitor.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
# Running at 7:10 and 19:10
cd /var/www/dir.../
bin/console --env=prod monitor:health --group=cli -q
```

I put the cron setup into their own files in `/etc/cron.d` but much the same would apply in any other crontab file. The shell script changes directory to the base directory of the project, and then runs `bin/console`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Now I get error message that www-data is not found:
`/bin/sh: 1: www-data: not found`

Comment: The different form of Cron/crontab files have slightly different formats. Files in `/etc/cron.*/` for example include a username to run the files as. Lines in the crontabs that are already on a per-user basis (ie `crontab -l` or `-e`) don't need that.

Comment: It is still not executing the command. I created this .sh file and checked with echo if it is being executed by the cron job. Everything is fine but my symfony command is still not executed. There is no output neither the commands does it's job. Here is a link to my .sh file: http://pastebin.com/wLuEQ710 I had to add the path to the php too

Answer (score -1):

Set the `--env` parameter in the cronjob command, like that:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /usr/lib/myApp/app/console  --env=prod >> /usr/lib/myApp/forumLog.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: damn, downvoter -- can't you see the error report in OP. make better answer instead!